# Install4j: Is it possible to run the installer in unattended mode simultaneously?

Tags: install4j

We use the installer to upgrade our applications on multiple servers. We use a script to do it. What we'd like to do is be able to kick off the installer in unattended mode (where the destination path is on the command that is executed, but the response file is shared). We would like to kick off several of these scripts simultaneously.

I have tried this, with 3 simultaneous installs, and it looks like one install completes, while the other 2 fail. Is there a commandline switch I need, to make this possible? I've looked in the help and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The installer prevents multiple simultaneous executions. In GUI mode, the second invocation would activate the first window, in unattended mode it simply fails.

From install4j 6.0.5 on, you can define the compiler variable "sys.ext.installerSingleInstance" and set it to "false" in order to prevent single instance mode for the installer and the uninstaller.

Comment: I'd like to get to the root of how the installer knows it is being run a second time. Is it a flag? registry entry? temp directory? This is critical to our next release of the product and this will create a bottleneck with our install team if they have to upgrade one host at one time (they have thousands!). Given that, I'm looking for possible workarounds. I was able to successfully launch the installer when it resided in 2 different directories, from the same machine. Both GUI's completed successfully without error. So, what makes this scenario work when the first scenario doesn't?

Comment: Please see my edit. If you want to get a pre-release build of 6.0.5, please contact support@ej-technologies.com.